# Expanding to fill remaining space in a CSS Grid layout

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-grid

I want to use CSS grid and the following is a mock-up of the aim:[image]

I'm building an interface that should expand rightward to fill the browser screen; my current code causes column 2 of the outer grid to be as wide as the browser *in addition* to column 1; or maybe one of it's children is causing this and it's just expanding to accommodate. Either way, it's spilling off the page horizontally

So the code:

```css
#main {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100%;
}

#col-2-outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
}

#row-1-inner {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

#col-2-inner table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="col-1-outer"></div>
  <div id="col-2-outer">
    <div id="row-1-inner"></div>
    <div id="row-2-inner">
      <div id="col-1-inner"></div>
      <div id="col-2-inner">
        <table></table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

FYI, for the time being I've forgone template areas until I get a handle on the basics (unless this somehow solves my problem but I gather this is strictly a code organization feature?).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `100%` for the 2nd column in your `grid-template-columns` is based on the width of the container - rather than occupying the space outstanding within the container, it will push out to the right because the 2nd column is trying to match the width of the container.

Try changing this to `auto` and this should rectify the issue, as it will only take up the space up to the end of the container and no further.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns

Answer (score 10):

I'd suggest to change your *markup* with a 3x2 grid like below:

1. Remove the *hierarchical* structure like you have in your code and add *one* element for each section in the *grid*.
2. Note that in the rule `grid-template-columns: 250px 150px auto`, 250px is the width of your `col-1-outer` and 150px is the width of the `col-1-inner`.
3. *Span* the first *column* over the two rows by using `grid-row: span 2`
4. *Span* the first *row* in the second *column* by using `grid-column: span 2`.
5. Extend the `table` over the last *grid item* by using 100% width and height.

See demo below:

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid; /* For illustration */
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 150px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 100px auto;
}

#col-1-outer {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

#row-1-inner {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

#col-2-inner table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="col-1-outer">col-1-outer</div>
  <div id="row-1-inner">col2-row-1-inner</div>
  <div id="col-1-inner">col2-row2-inner</div>
  <div id="col-2-inner">
    <table><tr><td>table</td></tr></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I gave the correct answer to the guy who solved my width issue, but, for what it's worth, this is indeed a better grid and I've adopted it,